# Sharing a mysql database remotely

Tags: mysql

I want to create a database and share the username and password with a friend who wants to access it remotely over the internet. I have mysql workbench installed but don't really know how to share a db remotely. Step by step instructions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

He needs to connect with the hostname (or ip address) of your machine (the MySQL server).

Port 3306 needs to be open so he can get to MySQL.

Can't provide step-by-step without knowing OS of both machines, network connection between the machines, client he will be using, etc, etc.

Comment: Yes got it! This is possible without lan or Ethernet right?

Comment: No.  You _either_ connect from the _same_ machine via a "socket", or you use TCP/IP across some form of LAN/WAN (Ethernet, WiFi, ...).  (It is also possible to connect locally via TCP/IP.)